# how to deserialize csv to class object C# using lumenworks csv reader

Tags: c#, lumenworks

I am using Lumenworks csv reader to read csv file. My problem is that after reading I have to deserialize it into class object . I have more than 100 columns in csv file and 100 properties in class. Please let me know how to do this.

Comment: Please write the question after you read Lumenworks manuals or examples and say where you are getting errors or what is making you trouble. otherwise the question is way to general and you are just saying your task.

Comment: Hint: Have a look into reflection.

Comment: @Some1Pr0: I have tried the example and will tell you where I am facin g the problem. I store the httpwebresponse into a csv file . When any column value contains comma  e.g Name column value for a row is STEVE, K  (lumenworks treats the comma in name value as next column value.)